# Error in finding the config variable while running the app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I'm getting error  while searching for location It is showing that Can't find variable config. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code, in [`App.js`](https://github.com/Natalia504/react-native-weatherApp/blob/master/src/App.js) line 20 it does:

```
import config from './config';`
```

and then it later uses that import on line 84:

```
axios.get(`https://api.wunderground.com/api/${config.apiKey}/geolookup/q/${this.state.latitude},${this.state.longitude}.json`)
```

Since there is no `config.js` file in the repo, it seems that is a file you need to create yourself to store app secrets, so it's a good thing it's not checked in since you wouldn't want others knowing your secrets.

If you wanted to be pretty awesome, you could create a PR against that repo that explains what needs to be done in the README so that others who use that code won't have the same problem :)

Comment: i need to generate the apikeys.

Comment: i have to put it in "axios.get(`https://api.wunderground.com/api/${config.apiKey}/geolookup/q/${this.state.latitude},${this.state.longitude}.json`)
"

Comment: where apikeys is wrriten?

Answer (score 0):

The config file is missing.

You will need to create your own config file which holds the API key which you will receive from [Wunderground's API](http://api.wunderground.com/).

Comment: how can i find api from there?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can see here http://api.wunderground.com/weather/api that Wunderground no longer provide free weather API keys. You will have to choose another weather API provider like https://openweathermap.org/api

Comment: i have added the new api also i.e  "         axios.get(`https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=M%C3%BCnchen,DE&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22`)
"

Comment: can't find variable:config

Comment: Check where config is imported and replace it

Comment: replace it with whom